# Magento get attribule value on pdf invoice

Tags: magento

I try to get a product attribute value on my invoice, but everything i tried found on stack doesn't give a result (getdata, getattribute, getressouce...)

Below is an extract of the file, i would like to replace the last line "getname" by getattribute

Thanks a lot

```
$order  = $this->getOrder();
        $item   = $this->getItem();
        $pdf    = $this->getPdf();
        $page   = $this->getPage();
        //$lines  = array();

        //if not only checking the height - let's check and set up page and background if needed
        if (!$returnHeight)
        {
            $blockHeight = $this->draw(true);

            if ($pdf->y - $blockHeight < 12)
            {
                $page = $pdf->newPage(array('table_header' => true));
                $this->setPage($page);
            }

            if ($pdf->currentItemWithBg)
            {
                $page -> setFillColor(new Zend_Pdf_Color_Html('#' . $pdf -> params['lightBg']));
                $page -> drawRectangle(18, $pdf -> y, $page->getWidth() - 18, $pdf -> y - $blockHeight, $fillType = Zend_Pdf_Page::SHAPE_DRAW_FILL);
            }
        }

        //get price and subtotal values
        $prices = $this->getItemPricesForDisplay();

        $topOffset = 10;

        //if there are labels leave more space at the top
        if (count($prices) > 0 && !empty($prices[0]['label']))
            $topOffset = 16;

        //slice product name into chunks
        $font = $pdf->_setFontLight($page, 9);

        $nameParts = $commonHelper->sliceStringByPoints($item->getName(), 191, $font, 9);
```

Comment: It looks like you have an orderItem - do you need to call `$item->getProduct()->getName()` ?

Comment: currently what is output of $item->getName() and is it customer/order/product attribute?